# Get list of times from a start time by 5 minutes

Tags: r

Let's say I have an "end time" which is now - 20 minutes

```
Sys.time()-20
"2015-09-17 13:06:45 CST"
```

and I would like to generate a vector that is time buckets from a "starttime" = "2015-09-17 10:00:00 CST"  to the end time in 5-minute bucket so the result I am looking for is:

```
10:05:00
10:10:00
10:15:00
....
....
11:00:00
11:05:00
11:10:00
....
....
13:00:00
13:05:00
```

do you know how to do that?

Comment: `seq(start, end, by = "5 mins")` ? Or `format(seq(start, end, by = "5 mins"), "%X")` if just need the time. (assuming `start` and `end` are of class `POSIXct` of course)

Answer (score 1):

To close this up, `seq` is a generic function which has a `seq.POSIXct` method and thus can understand time terminology in its `by` statement.

Lets say those are your `starttime` and `endtime`

```
(endtime <- Sys.time())
# [1] "2015-09-18 12:38:34 IDT"
(starttime <- endtime - 20*60)
# [1] "2015-09-18 12:18:34 IDT"
```

You can simply specify `by = "5 mins"` directly in `seq`

```
seq(starttime, endtime, by = "5 mins")
# [1] "2015-09-18 12:18:34 IDT" "2015-09-18 12:23:34 IDT" "2015-09-18 12:28:34 IDT" "2015-09-18 12:33:34 IDT"
# [5] "2015-09-18 12:38:34 IDT"
```

Or for exact output, you can modify the output using the `format` function

```
format(seq(starttime, endtime, by = "5 mins"), "%X")
# [1] "12:18:34" "12:23:34" "12:28:34" "12:33:34" "12:38:34"
```

---

JFI, R doesn't have a time class and those this is just a character string. You can check out the `chron` package if you want to use such class.